# C++ Initializing pointer two different ways results in two answers

Tags: c++, c, pointers, initialization

I'm sure this has probably been asked before, but I can't find anything on this. I am writing a C++ program that calls a C function that requires as one of it's inputs a pointer. It will then do some calculation and output an array via this same pointer. So an example of what I have is as follows.

```
double foo_init;
double *outarray =&foo_init;

cfunction(outarray);
```

This works as you would expect and the output of outarray is correct.

However, if I initialize another way, I only get 2 real values and the rest of the array is effectively zero (6.9e-310).

```
double *outarray= new double;
```

I'm sure I am missing something here but I was under the impression these two assignments are equivalent, but it is clear something is different. So what is going on?

Thanks,
Cameron

Comment: Which array? There is no array anywhere in this code.

Comment: `new double` allocates a single double. Use operator new[] to allocate an array

Comment: Usually when you get inexplicable results it means you have *undefined behaviour* because you are doing something wrong. This looks likely.

Comment: You are lucky that your first version works. And the second version exposes that you are not allocating the right type (double []),

Comment: You said you're missing something. There's a lot of that; us too. Like the definition of `cfunction()` and a description of what you at-least-hope it is supposed to be doing.

Comment: quantdev and gnometorule thank you for helpful feedback -- that has solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the pointers. In both cases you don't have enough memory to store your array. If pointer is pointing on single number, then you can change only this number.

First case fixed: `double arr[256]; double *p = arr;` (you can pass `arr` directly into function without creating `p`)

Second case fixed: `double *p = new double[256];`

Of course, you can replace 256 with any number you need.

If your current examples are working now, they can still sometimes cause crash.

Comment: Thank you. I see now that I had to initialize as much space as I am expecting the function to use. So I should always know in advance how large the expected output array will be?

Comment: @Cameron If you are using crappy functions that take a pointer and expect it to be of a certain size, then yes.

Answer (score 2):

Both cases have undefined behavior. You allocated space for a single `double`, either as an automatic variable on the stack in the first case, or on the heap with `new` in the second case, but your function writes more than one `double`.

When your code has undefined behavior, the compiler can do whatever it pleases, from crashing your program to silently returning wrong results to conjuring nasal demons to destroying the universe. Your first case "worked" entirely by accident.

Answer (score 1):

A single variable, like `foo_init`, is similar to an array containing one element.

The two assignments *are* equivalent, they both set `outarray` to point to an array containing one double. The only difference is that the array is on the stack in the first case, the heap in the second case. Also, in the first case array will be deallocated automatically when the function containing this code returns, while in the second case you must use `delete` to free the memory explicitly.

If `cfunction()` tries to access more than the first element of the array, it is invoking undefined behavior in both cases. You may not get an immediate error in some cases, but that's just getting lucky.

Comment: This makes sense now. I was confused about initializing a pointer to an array.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN of course. But the C function that I am calling does output this variable as an array so I just named it this way for convenience. Anyway, thanks for your comments. I think I finally have a handle on pointers now.